# Configure Moment.js to adapt different formats of different countries in the browser settings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, format, momentjs

I'm have a field in my web app that displays the date selected and I want it to change depending on the browser settings or adapt its format in different countries it is used.

I'm using moment.js in react, and this is how I coded it:

```
{moment(this.birthDate).format("DD.MM.YYYY")}
```

Comment: For an application that will be used in many different places, it's probably a better idea to present dates in an unambiguous format (e.g. DD MMM YYYY) since you don't know whether the user has set their system or browser to their preferred language. It's difficult to argue that a date should use any language other than the one used for the main content of the page.

Answer (score 1):

#### Moment.js with globalization (i18n)

Refer to

- document with keyword `Localized formats`: https://momentjs.com/docs/
- issue: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1875

> If you want to support any language you can import/require `moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js` instead of just `moment`.

And may use in the way as below:

```
moment().locale("hu", localization).format('LLL')
```

There are other noticeable points, kindly check them would help with your problem.

---

#### Read the browser language settings

Refer to

- article: [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/setting-up-internationalization-in-react-from-start-to-finish-6cb94a7af725/)

index.js

```
// Define user's language. Different browsers have the user locale defined
// on different fields on the `navigator` object, so we make sure to account
// for these different by checking all of them
const language =
  (navigator.languages && navigator.languages[0]) ||
  navigator.language ||
  navigator.userLanguage;
```

You can map from language to location via constant, or use other methods to achieve this, or read other browser localization settings.

Comment: How does this help the OP to change the format "depending on the browser settings or adapt its format in different countries"? Presumably that means more than just setting the "locale" to a language.

Comment: @RobG Updated, and if you have any good idea, feel free to post a new answer or make the edition.

Comment: For me, Safari says "en-AU", Firefox says "en-US", Chrome says "en-GB", Opera says "en-GB". BTW, globalization != internationalization.